# What size front derailleur do I need for a 11/32 cassette and medium rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, compatibility, front

Upgraded 11/32 cassette. looking for replacement front derailleur

Comment: Although the answer is fairly general for this question, it could be valuable to have details of the manufacturer and chainrings being used.

Answer (score 3):

Your front derailleur doesn't really care what's going on in back.

Here's what it does care about:

- The number of chainrings: don't use a derailleur for two rings with three, or vice-versa.
- The size of your big chainring: the arc of the outer cage plate should closely hug your big ring—for example, you ideally wouldn't use a road derailleur with smaller MTB-sized rings.
- The width of the chain: In my experience you have quite a bit of latitude on this point, but going by the book, you should use a front derailleur intended for use with a specific chain width, which is determined by the number of gears in back.

Comment: To be completely general, some Shimano RDs are designed for 1x, and should not be used with 2x. I think this applies to Campy Ekar also?

Comment: There is no factory 2x option for Ekar at all, so it would be a frankensteined setup to use it with 2x. You might be right about Shimano—I don't know.